# (Google Charts) How to make stacked column charts work with hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to sum the minutes of two bars on a bar chart and it breaks. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cristianojeda/x59Lfybj/31/)

I'm basing myself on the example from the [Stacked column charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#stacked-column-charts), but I can't get it to work with "H: i: s"

[image]

this is my code

```js
var GoogleColumnBasic = function() {
        var _googleColumnBasic = function() {
        google.charts.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['bar']});
        
        
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


    function drawChart() {

 var dtos= [];
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['','preparation time ', 'time when he retired', 
          { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['box 1',  '00:43:22',  '00:03:22',  ''],
        ['box 2',  '00:13:22', '00:73:22' , ''],
        ['box 3',  '00:23:22', '00:53:22', '']
      ]);

        
   var options = {
            height: 350,
           isStacked: true
          };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
           //chart.draw(data, options);
          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
        }

    
}
    return {
        init: function() {
            _googleColumnBasic();
        }
    }
}();
GoogleColumnBasic.init();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `'timeofday'` column, see [working with timeofday](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#working-with-timeofday).

> The DataTable timeofday column data type takes an array of either 3 or 4 numbers, representing hours, minutes, seconds, and optionally milliseconds, respectively. Using timeofday is different than using date and datetime in that the values are not specific to a date, whereas date and datetime always specify a date. For example, the time 8:30am would be: [8, 30, 0, 0], with the 4th value being optional ([8, 30, 0] would output the same timeofday value).

the data table used to draw the chart would be similar to the following...

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['', 'time of ', 'retirar', {role: 'annotation', type: 'string'}],
    ['Caja 1', [0, 43, 22], [0, 3, 22], ''],
    ['Caja 2', [0, 13, 22], [0, 73, 22], ''],
    ['caja 3', [0, 23, 22], [0, 53, 22], '']
  ]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
var GoogleColumnBasic = function() {
  var _googleColumnBasic = function() {
    google.charts.load('current', {
      packages: ['corechart']
    }).then(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['', 'time of ', 'retirar', {role: 'annotation', type: 'string'}],
        ['Caja 1', [0, 43, 22], [0, 3, 22], ''],
        ['Caja 2', [0, 13, 22], [0, 73, 22], ''],
        ['caja 3', [0, 23, 22], [0, 53, 22], '']
      ]);

      var options = {
        height: 350,
        isStacked: true,
        colors: ['#4285f4', '#a1c2fa'],
        theme: 'material',
        chartArea: {
          left: 64,
          top: 48,
          right: 32,
          bottom: 64,
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%'
        },
        height: '100%',
        legend: {
          position: 'top'
        },
        width: '100%'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, (options));
    }
  }
  return {
    init: _googleColumnBasic
  }
}();
GoogleColumnBasic.init();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart_div {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**NOTES**

1. the `jsapi` loader has been deprecated and should no longer be used.
   instead, use the new `loader.js`
   `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`
   this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet.
2. do not recommend using a *material* chart. (`google.charts.Bar`)
   they do not work well with `'timeofday'` columns,
   they do not support column roles such as `'annotation'`,
   AND many of the chart options simply do not work, see [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)
   instead, we can use option --> `theme: 'material'` on a classic chart (`google.visualization.ColumnChart`)

Comment: Your answer was very pleasant and accurate, thank you very much!!!